# Changing variable in php but same variable in javascript not changing

Tags: javascript, php, csv

I'm trying to create a google chart to display resource usage of a process over different periods of time. I am importing different csv files to a server and then read it using php, here's the php file:

```
   //PHPVar.php
    <?php
    class chartData
    {
        var $length;
        var $catagories;
        var $elements = array();
        var $numFiles;
        var $allFiles;       
        function startUp($input = 5)
        {
            $dir = "CSV";
            $this->allFiles = scandir($dir,1);
            $this->numFiles = count($this->allFiles) - 2;               

            $currentDir = $input;           
            $filePath = $dir;
            $filePath .= "/";
            $filePath .= $this->allFiles[intval($currentDir)];

            $file = fopen($filePath,"r");
            $this->elements=array(fgetcsv($file));

            while(! feof($file)
                $this->elements[]=fgetcsv($file);                   

            $this->length=count($this->elements);               
            $this->catagories=count($this->elements[0]);                
        }
    }
    $data = new chartData;
    //If there's a parameter input from AJAX then call startup to
    //refill the elements list
    if(isset($_POST['fileNumber']))
        $data->startUp($_POST['fileNumber']);
    //Else call startup with default parameter
    else
        $data->startUp();
    ?>
```

So the directory that I'm storing all my csv files is called CSV, so if there is no input to startup() then it will a specified file by default and store all of the values in the file into an array called elements[][]. I first create a chartData object and check if there is an input, if not then it means that this is the first call. In my webpage I have a dropdown menu which displays all the files in CSV directory, and I want it such that the graph refreshes with the values in the csv file that I chose. Here is the code I used to transfer the data (file that I chose) to php from javascript:

```
    function changeFile(str) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'PHPVar.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {fileNumber:str},
                    success: function(data) {console.log(data);}
                    });                    
                chart.clearChart();
                drawChart();
            }
```

So ultimately each entry in dropdown menu calls this function which should run PHPVar.php again to refresh the values. The first graph generated is fine, the problem is when I tried to change the csv file to plot. It seems that the php variable that I see in javascript is not changing whereas the php variables in PHPVar.php are. I have verified this by outputting values of some variable to console and the variables from PHPVar.php are indeed changing with each call from the dropdown menu, but it seems that no matter where I log the same variable in javascript using , the value remains the same as when I first start the website no matter how many times I call the function from the dropdown menu with different values. In the file that I draw the graph I used

```
    <?php include 'PHPVar.php' ?>
```

could it be that include is only making a copy of PHPVar.php and so when I go to change the variable I'm really changing it in PHPVar while a variable with the same name created by include remains unchanged? Any answers/suggestions are appreciated. Here is the js function:

```
            google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
            var data;
            var options;
            var time;
            var row;
            var selected = 1;
            var average = 0;
            var max = 0;
            var index;
            var size;
            var chart;

            function drawChart() {
                average = 0;
                max = 0;
                data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                var testArray = null;
                testArray = [];            
                <?php   
                //Export data from php server into javascript array *VERY SENSITIVE, make backup before changing*

                for($i=0;$i<$data->length-1;$i++)
                {
                ?>            
                    testArray[<?php echo $i; ?>] = [];
                    <?php

                    for($j=0;$j<$data->catagories;$j++)
                    {
                    ?>
                        <?php
                        if($j == 0 && $i != 0)
                        {
                            $timeStamp = array();
                            $time = preg_split('/-/', $data->elements[$i][0]);

                            $timeStamp = array(2015,(int)$time[0],(int)$time[1],(int)$time[2],(int)$time[3],(int)$time[4]);

                            ?>

                            testArray[<?php echo $i; ?>][<?php echo $j; ?>] = <?php echo json_encode($timeStamp,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>;

                        <?php
                        } else if($i == 0)
                        {
                        ?>
                            testArray[<?php echo $i; ?>][<?php echo $j; ?>] = '<?php echo $data->elements[$i][$j]; ?>'; 
                        <?php
                        } else
                        {
                        ?>
                            testArray[<?php echo $i; ?>][<?php echo $j; ?>] = <?php echo (int)$data->elements[$i][$j]; ?>; 
                        <?php
                        }
                    }
                }
                ?> 
                // Declare columns
                row  = testArray[0][selected];
                time = testArray[0][0];
                data.addColumn('datetime', time);
                data.addColumn('number', row);
                //alert(String(testArray[1][0][1]));
                for(index=1;index<<?php echo $data->length-1; ?>;index++)
                {
                    data.addRow([new Date(testArray[index][0][0],
                        testArray[index][0][1],
                        testArray[index][0][2],
                        testArray[index][0][3],
                        testArray[index][0][4],
                        testArray[index][0][5]), testArray[index][selected]]);
                    average += testArray[index][selected];
                    if(testArray[index][selected] > max)
                        max = testArray[index][selected];
                }
                average = average/<?php echo $data->length-1; ?>;
                var options = {
                    width: 900,
                    height: 500,
                    title: row,
                    hAxis: {
                      title: 'Time',
                      viewWindow: {
                      min: new Date(testArray[1][0][0],
                      testArray[1][0][1],
                      testArray[1][0][2],
                      testArray[1][0][3],
                      testArray[1][0][4],
                      testArray[1][0][5]),//testArray[1][0]),
                      max: new Date(testArray[<?php echo $data->length-2; ?>][0][0], 
                      testArray[<?php echo $data->length-2; ?>][0][1], 
                      testArray[<?php echo $data->length-2; ?>][0][2], 
                      testArray[<?php echo $data->length-2; ?>][0][3], 
                      testArray[<?php echo $data->length-2; ?>][0][4], 
                      testArray[<?php echo $data->length-2; ?>][0][5])
                      },
                      gridlines: 
                      {
                          count: -1,
                          units:
                          {
                              days: {format: ['MMM dd']},
                              hours: {format: ['HH:mm', 'ha']}
                          }
                      },
                      minorGridlines:
                      {
                          units: 
                          {
                            hours: {format: ['hh:mm:ss a', 'ha']},
                            minutes: {format: ['HH:mm a Z', ':mm']}
                          }
                      }
                    },
                    vAxis: {
                      title: 'Resource'
                    },
                    backgroundColor: '#f1f8e9'
                };

                chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

                chart.draw(data, options);
                document.getElementById('Average').innerHTML = "Mean Resource Usage: "+ average;
                document.getElementById('Max').innerHTML = "Max Resource Usage: "+ max;

            }
```

Comment: Is that the full contents of the `PHPVar.php` file? You're making an AJAX request to it but there doesn't seem to be any response sent in PHP.

Comment: Hello Ted. This is a misunderstanding of the http request response cycle -  im guessing that the javascript function `drawChart` relies on variables printed directly into the js from php. These variables will never change after the initial page load. Instead have the function except the variables it needs in arguments, then pass them from the ajax response, eg `drawChart(data.graphdata)`. Of course you will have to modify your php to return this data

Comment: If you show your js code as well, probably i can help you with that

Comment: @Ted I agree with Steve that we would need to see the full code in order to help more ... This is not really clear ...

Comment: @Steve I have added the js function to the post, I didn't know if i should since it is quite long, but it is like you said, I am using variables printed directly into the js from php

Comment: @Steve Also, I'm not quite sure I understand what you meant. So I should have drawCharts accept a parameter which contains all the data I want to plot, and those data are returned from the ajax call? If it's not too much to ask could you explain how I would return php data from the ajax call?

Comment: @Steve Nevermind, I figured it out. Anyways, the issue was exactly the one you pointed out, I thought that <?php...?> would return the current variable. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be with your jQuery ajax call :

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'PHPVar.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {fileNumber:str},
  success: function(data) {console.log(data);}
});
```

By default, jQuery .ajax() is caching results.

So you might want to disable caching by default, by doing something like :

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

Somewhere before in your initialisation JS code.

Comment: I doubt thats the issue, much more likely its the fact OP does nothing with the returned data, and is instead expecting the hard coded php variables in his js to be updated

Comment: @Steve ... I'm not sure .. I understand your point .. But we miss the rest of the code to be sure .. I was saying that about jQuery caching because he is saying that initially it's working for the first time then it's not ...

Comment: True, im only guessing - my theory is "the 1st time" is initial page load, when the php variables will be injected into the js.